# Checking out a different branch while a script is running?

Tags: python, bash, git

I'm using git for version control of my project. I'm working on a feature on a new branch of my project that requires a very long test to be performed, like ~5 hours for the test to be completed. I've written a python script as part of this branch in order to test the feature.

Suppose that I want to work on a different feature, on a different branch, while this test is running. Is it safe for me to open up a new terminal window and checkout the other branch to work on the other feature while the test is running on this branch?

Comment: just checkout the project twice.

Comment: I don't think there will be any consequences since python precompiles (as long as you start the test prior to switching). However if you run into an exception the reported line numbers could be wrong. Anyway, i suggest you take @JimmyEngelbrecht's approach.

Comment: @JimmyEngelbrecht do you mean I should duplicate the repository and checkout the branch again on the duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) : this command allows you to have two  checkouts on your disk (in two different folders) from the same git repo.

Another solution is : setup a CI server, which can run such tasks on another station.